# Best practice using an arrow function in a React class component with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I'm trying to understand the difference between two ways of using an arrow function and setting state in a React class component. Both seem to work and set the state correctly.

In a controlled component, I call the function in question like this.

`<input onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter name" />`

The two ways I've seen these functions defined are like;

**Method 1.**

```
handleChange = (e) => this.setState({ name: e.target.value});
```

**Method 2**

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
};
```

My question is:

1. Is one preferred over the other and why?
2. Isn't method 1 returning a value from the function, compared to method 2 which just executes its content?

Here's a working code snippet of the controlled input.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { name: '' }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => this.setState({ name: e.target.value});

  handleChange2 = (e) => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter name" />
        <p>{this.state.name || 'no name yet'}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

 <div id="root"></div>
```

Any help in clarifying this and what is regarded as best practice will be helpful.

Comment: An arrow function without the function body `{}` will also return the single statement implicitly, like you said. If you don't want the return value, you can still write it without the function body and just ignore the returned value, if you find that way of writing better. It's just a matter of taste.

Comment: They are effectively the same thing since both will return `undefined`. setState doesn't return a value, and the second one doesn't provide a return value

Comment: they're the same thing, the first one is implicitly returning. You also don't need the parenthesis around the `(e)` in option 1 since it's a single argument

Comment: @GhostCat, no worries. This is indeed helpful and makes sense. I'll read through the triage thread again you posted in the comments. [see help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) as that provides more context as to where I went wrong.

Comment: I appreciate the quick and kind comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1** is clean and simpler to read. It does not return anything. Notice that this method does not need the parenthesis around `e`.

**Method 2** is preferred in case you want to do more than a change in state (`setState()`) when the text is changed. For example, you want to call another function or if you simply want to somehow validate the input. In addition, you can return a value if you add a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleChange = (e) => this.setState({ name: e.target.value});
```

is the same thing as

```
handleChange = e => {
    return this.setState({ name: e.target.value});
};
```